# How can a Decimal type's precision and scale be determined?

Tags: breeze

It doesn't appear as though the breeze metadata includes the precision and scale of decimal types.  It simply identifies a property as "Decimal".  The information is available in EF models.  Is this something that could be added to the metadata or is the information already there somewhere but I'm just not seeing it?

Answer (score 0):

We don't expose it in the metadata right now, but it is a reasonable request.  Can you add this to the [Breeze User Voice](https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions) ?  We use this to prioritize new features and take it very seriously.

We have also discussed 'formally' supporting extensible metadata. I say formally because there is nothing stopping you from adding additional properties to the 'dataProperty' metadata objects right now.